# Is there a way to cluster a curve in r using K-means using slope rather than value?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, k-means

I'm trying to cluster the following curve in r using the K-means method into 2 groups. When I run the K-means I get the positive values clustered together and the negative clustered together. I'm trying to cluster them according to their slope where the first group would be when the slope is positive, and the second when the slope is negative.
I'm pretty sure the answer would be to transform the curve into its slope values, but not sure how to get a moving slope of the curve.
I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

[image: The first is of the curve, the second is of the current result, the third is of the intended result]

Comment: Your example is `sin` and it is easy to compute the derivative.  Do you know the function and its derivative - or do you just have data?

Comment: It looks like a sine curve, but it's not an exact sine curve. Also I don't have an equation that I could calculate the derivative for, just data.

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you want. I created some junk test data.

```
##  Some sample data - not sin, but pretty close.
set.seed(1234)
x = sort(runif(200, -pi, pi))
y = sin(x) * (1 + x/20)


## Get derivative
DERIV = diff(y)/diff(x)

## Set up blank plot
plot(x,y, type='n')

## Add curve
segments(x[-length(x)], y[-length(y)], x[-1], y[-1], 
    col=as.numeric(DERIV>0)+1)
```

[image: Curve - colored by sign of the slope]

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe your answer put me in the right direction!